# View item of linked list

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I want to view all the items of a linked list.

I've created a three items list, and when i use the below "show_items" function, it just show the first element, and the other items can't be showed becuase a segmentation fault error is given by compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list{
    int age;
    struct list *next;
};

void create_item(int *total_items, struct list *where_is_first_item, struct list *where_is_last_item)
{
struct list *generic_item;
generic_item = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
printf("\nage of item %d: ", (*total_items)+1);
scanf("%d", &generic_item->age);

if(*total_items == 0){

    where_is_first_item->next=generic_item;
    where_is_last_item->next=generic_item;
    printf("\nitem created\n");
}
else{

    where_is_last_item->next=generic_item;
    printf("\nitem created\n");
}

void show_items(int *total_items, struct list *where_is_first_item, struct list *temp){
    temp=where_is_first_item->next;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<*total_items;i++){
        printf("age of element %d: %d\n", i+1, temp->age);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}

int main (void){
    int total_items=0;
    struct list *where_is_first_item;
    where_is_first_item=malloc(sizeof(struct list));        
    struct list *temp;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    printf("\n\n\tCREATE A NEW ITEM\n");
    create_item(&total_items, where_is_first_item, where_is_last_item);
    total_items++;
    show_items(&total_items, where_is_first_item, temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You dont seem to initialize your values.

Comment: You still don't initialize `generic_item->next`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating through your list, you should be checking the value of `temp` to make sure it isn't `NULL` before trying to access it.  At the least, you should use the following:

```
for ( i = 0; i < *total_items && temp != NULL; i++ )
 ...
```

although it's more common to iterate through a list like

```
while ( temp != NULL ) // or just while ( temp )
{
  ...
  temp = temp->next;
}
```

Your usage of `temp` seems confused; does it serve any purpose in `main` after you've called `show_items`?  If not, you should make it local to `show_items` and not pass it as an argument:

```
void show_items(int *total_items, struct list *where_is_first_item)
{
  struct list *temp = where_is_first_item->next;
  ...
}
```

In the code you've posted, `total_items` is initialized to 0; as written, this code shouldn't attempt to output anything.  It would make life easier for everyone if you would either post the actual code you're having problems with, or if it's too big, reduce it to a representative sample of the problem.

**Edit**

Duh.  Now I see the problem. You're never properly setting the `next` item in your `generic_item` struct.

So you have two pointers to keep track of the head and tail of your list, `where_is_first_item` and `where_is_last_item`.  When you add the first item to the list, you create `generic_item` and set your head and tail pointers to point to it through their respective `next` members, giving you something like this (using `head` and `tail` instead of `where_is_first_item` and `where_is_last_item` for brevity):

```
head           generic_item   tail
+--+--+        +--+--+        +--+--+
|  | -+------->|  | -+-???    |  | -+---+
+--+--+        +--+--+        +--+--+   |
               ^                        |
               |                        |
               +------------------------+
```

So far so good.  However, when you add a second item, you only update the list tail pointer; you don't create an explicit link from the first item to the second, so you wind up with something like the following:

```
head                          generic_item    tail
+--+--+        +--+--+        +--+--+         +--+--+
|  | -+------->|  | -+-???    |  | -+-???     |  | -+--+
+--+--+        +--+--+        +--+--+         +--+--+  |
                              ^                        |                         
                              |                        |
                              +------------------------+
```

Hopefully you can see the problem. The `next` pointer in the first list element is never initialized, so it contains an indeterminate value that doesn't correspond to a valid address.

You need an extra step when you append a new element to the list:

```
struct list *pre = where_is_last_item->next;
pre->next = generic_item;
where_is_last_item->next = generic_item;
```

That will give you something like the following:

```
head           pre            generic_item    tail
+--+--+        +--+--+        +--+--+         +--+--+
|  | -+------->|  | -+------->|  | -+-???     |  | -+--+
+--+--+        +--+--+        +--+--+         +--+--+  |
                              ^                        |                         
                              |                        |
                              +------------------------+
```

As a rule, you should always initialize the `next` member to `NULL`, rather than leave it indeterminate.  It's easy to test against `NULL`; it's much harder to determine the validity of a non-`NULL` pointer value.

Comment: let's try to shettle this. I don't used NULL cause it was just a test, so i only executed the "show_items" function once my three items were created.Later in a final version i will use your workaround.
i should put the temp as a local variable in the show_items function, but again i put in the main just for testing to avoid the errors, i was wrong.
the problem still remains, why there's a segmentation fault when i want to show more than one item of the linked list?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see two major issues in the code that you're showing us:

1. I don't see three members being created like you claim in the problem statement.
2. The memory returned by `malloc()` has unspecified contents, and you're expecting it to have useful contents.

And then for just odd things:

1. Why do you pass `total_items` as a pointer if you never modify it.
2. Why do you pass `temp` as an argument if you promptly ignore the value you passed in?